# Whats the best way to shift list items visually?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a `<ul>` that has a bunch of `<li>`s.

Some of the `<li>`s need to have certain formatting for example

```
a
b
    c
    d
e
```

I can't have an `<li>` contain a `<ul>` so for now I'm wrapping the c and d in a `<div>` with the left-margin set. Is this safe to do, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you have a `ul` inside of a `li`?

Comment: @Blender: technical reasons, it would break my jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write like this:

CSS:

```
ul{
     list-tyle:none;
}
li{
    margin:5px 0;
}
.shift{
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li class="shift">c</li>
    <li class="shift">d</li>
    <li>e</li>
</ul>
```

Check this live http://jsfiddle.net/KuNWf/

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't a good idea.

`ul` elements contain *only* `li` elements. Nothing more. If the browser renders it fine today, don't expect it to function tomorrow, as you are working with non-standard behavior.

The standard is defined [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html#edef-UL).

Is there any reason for why you cannot nest `ul` tags?

Comment: i can't have a ul inside an li. Can I do this? `<ul><li>a</li><ul><li>b</li></ul></ul>` is that valid?

Comment: @qwertymk: Yes, that is the way to nest lists. **EDIT: Never mind** - Blender is right, you can only insert `<li>` elements into `<ul>`s.

Comment: @Nightfirecat: No, it isn't. The only tags that can be in `ul`s are `li`s.

Answer (score 0):

That will work.

The other option may be using CSS to handle it like this:

```
        .myUl{
            margin:0px;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        .myUl .marginless {
            margin: 0px;
        }
        .myUl .margin {
            margin: 0px;
            margin-left: 20px;
        }


    <ul class="myUl">
        <li class="marginless">a</li>
        <li class="marginless">b</li>
        <li class="margin">c</li>
        <li class="margin">d</li>
        <li class="marginless">e</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Please, don't advocate using broken HTML ;)

Comment: @Blender: When people learn to use tips, this does not matter.

Comment: Just because something is working doesn't mean that it is safe. Web standards are there for a reason (and it isn't to make your life difficult).